# HTTP Request Timeout results in nodejs app freeze

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post, timeout

I have this piece of code which posts some data to a specific link and returns a response.

```
post2 = async function(url, data, h) {
  const dataString = JSON.stringify(data)

  let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': dataString.length,
    },
    timeout: 3000, // in ms
  }

  if(h) options.headers = {...options.headers, ...h};

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = http.request(url, options, (res) => {
      if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode > 299) {
        return reject(new Error(`HTTP status code ${res.statusCode}`))
      }

      const body = []
      res.on('data', (chunk) => body.push(chunk))
      res.on('end', () => {
        const resString = Buffer.concat(body).toString()
        resolve(resString)
      })
    })

    req.on('error', (err) => {
      reject(err)
    })

    req.on('timeout', () => {
      req.destroy()
      reject(new Error('Request time out'))
    })

    req.write(dataString)
    req.end()
  })
}
```

Im calling post like this:

```
async function test(){
  let status = await post(`http://mylink.com/etc`, {id: 123});
  console.log(status);
}
```

Whenever the requests lands in the 'timeout' state the application freezes for a couple seconds, and I can't figure out why. Could "new Error" in reject cause this?

I couldn't reproduce the issue exactly, I have this print though:

```bash
Error: Request time out
 at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/public/Application.js:83:14)
 [90m    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:314:20)[39m
 [90m    at Socket.emitRequestTimeout (_http_client.js:769:9)[39m
 [90m    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)[39m
 [90m    at Socket.emit (events.js:326:22)[39m
 [90m    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:482:8)[39m
 [90m    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)[39m
 [90m    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)[39m
```